# Website Registration Date

Tags: domains

I recently registered a website : cinematrailers.net.

I was aware that this domain was expired ( registered in 2007 until 2011)

My question is when I go to view the registration date on this domain, it says 2012 instead of 2007.

Why is that when it was clearly registered in 2007?

And will this affect seo? I was under the assumption that the domains age would be great for seo, but now I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the domain was expired and you purchased it from a registrar, rather than transferring ownership directly from the old registrant, then the creation date would be reset. That said, there might still be links to it from other places on the web, which is more important in terms of Pagerank.

Matt Cutts, Google's head of web spam, answered the SEO question a while back in [a YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-pnpg00FWJY). Short answer: don't worry about the creation date listed in the WHOIS data.